# Microsoft Word changing colours of theme

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, eclipse, themes

I want to move some highlighted code from Eclipse into Microsoft Word. But whenever I try to copy the text over the colours are modified slightly (bright green is changed to a duller green, pink is changed to a lighter pink... etc...) I want to know if there is a way to allow my copied code to keep the same colours when copied.

The reason I want to copy the code is because I want to adjust some sizes for certain parts and print it out (I'm making a poster but I liked the highlighting from my coloured theme in Eclipse)

Is there any alternate or solution?

Comment: Is the imported text given different styles, or is it all direct formatting?

Comment: @Adam sorry im not sure what that means

Comment: Not a problem, please see [this](http://jahangiri.us/2013/using-styles-not-direct-formatting-in-microsoft-word/) page for an explanation of the two and how to use the Style inspector to find which one your imported text uses.